# Is there a way to filter a dataframe to keep values that are matching values in another dataframe?

Tags: r, filter

Here I have dataframe df2 that Has three values in column B. I want to filter df1$B by keeping only values that match df2$B.

```
df2 <- structure(list(A = 1:3, B = c(20L, 7L, 52L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df1 <- structure(list(A = 1:6, B = c(15L, 20L, 13L, 7L, 52L, 78L)), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `r base`, you can write:

```r
df1[df1$B %in% df2$B,]

  A  B
2 2 20
4 4  7
5 5 52
```

---

Using `dplyr` package, you can use `filter`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% filter( B %in% df2$B)

  A  B
1 2 20
2 4  7
3 5 52
```

---

You can also do a `left_join`:

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(df2, df1, by = "B")

  A.x  B A.y
1   1 20   2
2   2  7   4
3   3 52   5
```

Is it what you are looking for ?